# How to show info window?

Tags: google-maps

Hi guys been trying my best to solve this problem. I can't see info window even after clicking the marker

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() { //Initalize JS after onload
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), { 
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
});




var randomPoint0 = new google.maps.LatLng(18.9750, 72.8258); //First Location


var marker0 = new google.maps.Marker({ //Set up marker
       position: randomPoint0,
       map: map
    });

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('locationid0'), 'click', //Set up DOM listener 1
    function(){
        map.setZoom(13);
     map.setCenter(marker0.getPosition());  
    });


var randomPoint1 = new google.maps.LatLng(19.8833, 76.7833); //First Location


var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ //Set up marker
       position: randomPoint1,
       map: map
    });

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('locationid1'), 'click', //Set up DOM listener 1
    function(){
        map.setZoom(13);
     map.setCenter(marker1.getPosition());  
    });


var randomPoint2 = new google.maps.LatLng(25.6000, 85.1167); //First Location


var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({ //Set up marker
       position: randomPoint2,
       map: map
    });

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('locationid2'), 'click', //Set up DOM listener 1
    function(){
        map.setZoom(13);
     map.setCenter(marker2.getPosition());  
    });


var randomPoint3 = new google.maps.LatLng(18.5333, 73.8667); //First Location


var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({ //Set up marker
       position: randomPoint3,
       map: map
    });

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('locationid3'), 'click', //Set up DOM listener 1
    function(){
        map.setZoom(13);
     map.setCenter(marker3.getPosition());  
    });


var randomPoint4 = new google.maps.LatLng(22.3000, 70.7833); //First Location


var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({ //Set up marker
       position: randomPoint4,
       map: map
    });

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('locationid4'), 'click', //Set up DOM listener 1
    function(){
        map.setZoom(13);
     map.setCenter(marker4.getPosition());  
    });


var randomPoint5 = new google.maps.LatLng(17.8625, 78.886); //First Location


var marker5 = new google.maps.Marker({ //Set up marker
       position: randomPoint5,
       map: map
    });

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('locationid5'), 'click', //Set up DOM listener 1
    function(){
        map.setZoom(13);
     map.setCenter(marker5.getPosition());  
    });


var randomPoint6 = new google.maps.LatLng(13.0833, 80.2833); //First Location


var marker6 = new google.maps.Marker({ //Set up marker
       position: randomPoint6,
       map: map
    });

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('locationid6'), 'click', //Set up DOM listener 1
    function(){
        map.setZoom(13);
     map.setCenter(marker6.getPosition());  
    });


var randomPoint7 = new google.maps.LatLng(28.6167, 77.2167); //First Location


var marker7 = new google.maps.Marker({ //Set up marker
       position: randomPoint7,
       map: map
    });

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('locationid7'), 'click', //Set up DOM listener 1
    function(){
        map.setZoom(13);
     map.setCenter(marker7.getPosition());  
    });


var randomPoint8 = new google.maps.LatLng(19.9833, 73.8000); //First Location


var marker8 = new google.maps.Marker({ //Set up marker
       position: randomPoint8,
       map: map
    });

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('locationid8'), 'click', //Set up DOM listener 1
    function(){
        map.setZoom(13);
     map.setCenter(marker8.getPosition());  
    });


var randomPoint9 = new google.maps.LatLng(30.7343, 76.7933); //First Location


var marker9 = new google.maps.Marker({ //Set up marker
       position: randomPoint9,
       map: map
    });

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('locationid9'), 'click', //Set up DOM listener 1
    function(){
        map.setZoom(13);
     map.setCenter(marker9.getPosition());  
    });


var randomPoint10 = new google.maps.LatLng(22.5697, 88.3697); //First Location


var marker10 = new google.maps.Marker({ //Set up marker
       position: randomPoint10,
       map: map
    });

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('locationid10'), 'click', //Set up DOM listener 1
    function(){
        map.setZoom(13);
     map.setCenter(marker10.getPosition());  
    });




    map.setCenter(marker0.getPosition());
    map.setZoom(5);

 var info = message;

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: message
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });


}



</script>
```

this is my link
http://www.safarikidindia.com/safari-map.php#

All the marker pins are dynamic so how I can show address text, can you please advice

Comment: There are no [InfoWindows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows) in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to had an infoWindow for each marker!

Supposing you have 10 different messages, stored in 10 variables (message0, message1, message2,...), you should write:

```
    var infoWindow0 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: message0
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker0, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow0.open(map, marker0);
    });


    var infoWindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: message1
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow1.open(map, marker1);
    });


    var infoWindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: message2
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow2.open(map, marker2);
    });

...(and so on until marker10)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I did manage to do it. Thanks for the effort. Here is it http://www.safarikidindia.com/contact_list.php